# save data from in input in a table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

thanks u for u help
i'm working on a school project. I'm trying to save some data so let me explain :[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA3fK.png)
so in the picture,  for each exercice i have a mark.
there is a table for exercice to get the exercice name, and i want to save the mark of each exercice, in a table called mark_exercice which contain the id the the exercice and the mark of course. her is the code i did until now :

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-eiws">Exercice</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">M</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">E</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">C</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">B</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">A</th>
  </tr>
    <?php foreach ($missionsPns['exercicespn'] as $key => $missionsPn): ?>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo h($missionsPn['NOM']); ?></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><div ><input name="data[noteexercice][note]"  value="M" type="checkbox"  id="NoteM"></div></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][note]"  value="E" type="checkbox"  id="NoteE"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][note]"  value="C" type="checkbox"  id="NoteC"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][note]"  value="B" type="checkbox"  id="NoteB"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][note]"  value="A" type="checkbox"  id="NoteA"></td>

  </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

when i do the debug for the request data i got this :     array(

```
    'noteexercice' => array(
        'note' => 'A'
    )
)
```

so i wish i could save the mark with the id of the name of the exercice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-eiws">Exercice</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">M</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">E</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">C</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">B</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">A</th>
  </tr>
    <?php foreach ($missionsPns['exercicespn'] as $key => $missionsPn): ?>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"><?php echo h($missionsPn['NOM']); ?></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><div ><input name="data[noteexercice][$missionsPn['ID']][]"  value="M" type="checkbox"  id="NoteM"></div></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][$missionsPn['ID']][]"  value="E" type="checkbox"  id="NoteE"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][$missionsPn['ID']][]"  value="C" type="checkbox"  id="NoteC"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][$missionsPn['ID']][]"  value="B" type="checkbox"  id="NoteB"></td>
<td class="tg-0lax"><input name="data[noteexercice][$missionsPn['ID']][]"  value="A" type="checkbox"  id="NoteA"></td>

  </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

So will have an output like this:

```
array(
    '1' => array('C', 'B', 'A'),
    '2' => array('B'),
    '3' => array('M', 'A')
);
```

And than you can save it like:

```
$this->loadModel('MarkExercise');
foreach($data as $dataKey => $dataValue) {
    foreach ($dataValue as $datum) {
        $toSave = array('exercise_id' => $dataKey, 'mark' =>  $datum);
        this->MarkExercise->save($toSave);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help.